# RxJs. How to wait for other observable if it fired recently

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

Basically I have two subscriptions that fire events now and then.

First one is pretty straightforward, it loads and displays some data:

```
observableOne$.switchMap(event => {
  return loadData(event);
}).subscribe(data => {
  displayData(data);
});
```

Second one transform displayed data, and the transformation should be done only once:

```
observableTwo$.subscribe(event => {
  transformDisplayedData(event);
});
```

The problem I am facing is that if second event is fired right after first, then transformation is lost. And I can't reapply, it is one time action.

Is there a way to postpone transformation if `observableOne$` fired recently?

Time sequence will look like so:

```
One      : -a----------a----->
Two      : -----b------b----->
Display  : ---a----------a---> // lag is due to async data loading
Transform: -----b--------b--->
```

**EDIT**

I have created a [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/WiseBird/mc8h52r7/2/) with demonstration. The actual time sequence can be written like this:

```
PageClick      : -x----------x----->
HighlightClick : -----x------x----->
DataRender     : ---x----------x--->
DataHighlight  : -----x------x----->
```

When PageClick and HighlightClick come together data is highlighted and a second later rendered. But I want to postpone highlighting, hence desired time sequence:

```
PageClick      : -x----------x----->
HighlightClick : -----x------x----->
DataRender     : ---x----------x--->
DataHighlight  : -----x--------x--->
```

Comment: How, why and when you trigger `observableTwo$` if you know it's triggered right after `observableOne$` and you know it shouldn't? There're operators such as `throttle()` or `debounce()` but it's hard to give you any advice when it's not obvious what your code does.

Comment: @Martin, Is it more clear with sequence diagram?

Comment: Why can't you put `transformDisplayedData(event);` right before `displayData(data);`?

Comment: @Martin, You mean in `subscribe` for `observableOne$`? Because transformation is controlled by second event. And if first event happens without second then no transformation needed.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the purpose is, even with the diagram.  But I think you're answer is either using .share() or a ReplaySubject.

Comment: @D.Walsh Check this [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/WiseBird/mc8h52r7/2/). When clicking 'both' button highlighting is lost soon after it is applied.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle!  I'm not clear which action is one and which is two.  With respect to the fiddle, what's the relevant sequence, what does it do now, and what should it do?

Comment: @D.Walsh I want to postpone highlighting until new data is rendered.

Comment: Duplicate based on accepted answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40636035/postpone-observable-when-other-one-fired-in-rxjs/40822369#40822369

Comment: @subhaze, Yes, you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone interested it can be done via introducing intermediate stream, through which events `start loading` and `end loading` are passing. For more details refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40636035/postpone-observable-when-other-one-fired-in-rxjs/40822369#40822369)