# Postpone observable when other one fired in RxJs

Tags: rxjs5, reactivex

I have a table on a page and two subscriptions:

1. First one reloads table data. It has a delay because it calls an api.
2. Second highlights data. Does not affect table data.

When subscriptions fire one by one everything is OK, but when they fire at the same time data is highlighted and soon after is reloaded so highlighting is gone.

You can see it [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/WiseBird/mc8h52r7/2/).

Is there are way to postpone highlighting if reloading is in action?

Probably I can accomplish this by introducing `loading` variable but I am looking for reactiveX solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that in rxjs everything is a stream, which you can use to your advantage, I've modified you fiddle a bit so that everything is a stream now:

```
  var pageClicks = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.getElementById('page'),  'click');
  var highlightClicks = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.getElementById('highlight'), 'click');
  var bothClicks = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.getElementById('both'), 'click');

  var page = 0;
  var nextPage$ = Rx.Observable.of(page)
    .map(function() {
      page = (page + 1) % 2;
      return page
    })
    .switchMap(loadData)
    .do(renderData);

  var doBoth$ = nextPage$
    .do(highlight);

  // initial rendering of data
  doBoth$.subscribe();

  pageClicks
    .switchMapTo(nextPage$)
    .subscribe();

  highlightClicks
    .do(highlight)
    .subscribe();

  bothClicks
    .switchMapTo(doBoth$)
    .subscribe();
```

Here is the link to the updated fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/r2L7k0mc/3/

---

Based on your comments I have updated your fiddle with the following code:

```
  var page$ = events.page$.share();
  var loadData$ = page$
    .startWith(0)
    .switchMap(page => loadData(page).takeUntil(page$))
    .do(renderData);
  loadData$.subscribe();

  var loading$ = Rx.Observable.merge(
    page$.mapTo(true),
    loadData$.mapTo(false)
  )
    .startWith(false)
    .publishReplay(1);
  loading$.connect();

  events.highlight$
    .switchMap(function() {
        return loading$
        .filter(function(isLoading) { return !isLoading; })
        .take(1);
    })
    .do(highlight)
    .subscribe();
```

See: https://fiddle.jshell.net/mc8h52r7/5/

However I would strongly suggest to rethink the architecture, since this is a very ugly set of streams, that could surely be optimized with a different architecture.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle and the code here, it should work properly now - for some reason it only works when subscribing the event before having the click-streams subscribed - this might be a possible rxjs bug even

Comment: I changed rxjs to beta.12 and the version with `doBoth$.subscribe()` at the end started working. So indeed looks like a bug in rxjs.

Comment: OK regarding the solution. You have used bothClicks stream to call actions one after another, but in my case I do not have an access to such stream I only see two events. I changed [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/mc8h52r7/4/) to reflect this. I am sorry I failed to express it at the beginning.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly: Sub1 => Loading!; Sub2 => Highlighting!; if Sub2 triggers, while the data is loading => Highlighting should wait! - is this correct?

Comment: That sounds to me like a very unusual usecase and is in fact not possible without the introduction of an additional stream, I have updated your fiddle to get it to work, however I would strongly suggest, that you rethink the architecture of your usecase: https://fiddle.jshell.net/mc8h52r7/5/